# Problems with version of kgdb patch

Tags: kgdb

My kernel version is 2.6.35. 
I cannot find a kgdb 2.6.35 online.

Anyone has idea about which version of kgdb can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after kernel 2.6.35, both kgdb and kdb are embedded in kernel source tree, so there are no patched file for them.